# angularjs - update part of UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have a timer running every 100ms and can't afford to do digest cycles on the whole app (becomes too slow on mobile devices and probably not a good idea anyway since nothing else changes but the timer indicator).

I am using Material library's progress to show the timer status (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressCircular)

What I would like to do:

1. setTimer to set the timer (not $timer/$interval as that triggers the whole update) (easy).
2. Tell just the progress indicator to update its UI (**not sure how?**).

I don't have a custom progress indicator, otherwise, I can probably just set the raw parameters myself when setTimer finishes. That's my backup plan if I can't find any solution here, I'll probably just make a linear progress indicator and update the width css when the setTimer is triggered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How large is your scope? If you use an isolate scope (single directive/controller) which has the timer as its only property, there shouldn't be a lot of overhead to digesting that scope.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Right now I have a timerService which runs the timer and keeps track of the count. That timer service is injected in a couple of controllers which surface that count to the directive. I am not sure how the scope is isolated. Does this mean that every controller where I inject timerService will be digested when a timer in timerService ends? In that case, I should just create a new controller/directive for just the timer and isolate the digest like that. Is this understanding correct? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Does the service need to update the timer in realtime (progress indicator)? Or is it just a linear counter counting up from 0 or counting down to 0? Then I'd just write it as a directive, something along the lines of `<timer count-to="model.deadline">`. That should give you the opportunity for a very small isolated scope.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the difference. I have a game where players get 10 seconds to make their turn. During this time, nothing else changes, just the circular timer needs to be updated to indicate time for the rest of the players. Once they make their move, the server sends new data and the whole UI is updated. The timerService currently resets the timer to 0 whenever game state changes and then counts up to 10 seconds again. I do have a separate timer directive, but I feel it still causes too many digest cycles (noticed by placing a console.log statement in some other part of UI)

Comment: Have you tried $rootScope emit and broadcast?

Comment: You could also place the timer inside a directive that re-$compiles itself every x ms, by polling the service where the timer is. Have you considered using angular timer ? https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/ 
Maybe you can wire it directly to the angular-material md-progress directive.

Comment: Thank you Christian. I am relatively new to Angular and am presuming $rootScope emit/broadcast would trigger a full update also, no? The second suggestion to re-$compile sounds interesting but can you please guide me a little more. In that case, would I be manipulating the DOM myself after each compile, how does that work? Also, thanks for the Angular Timer link, I will try to see what they have done to avoid this and maybe I can do something similar.